# How to log colorful message in Debug Console Logs (Flutter Android studio)?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, logging

I'm trying to  add ANSI colours to the log message but
I'm Getting the white message with the colour code.
my code:

```
developer.log('\x1B[34m msg \x1B[0m');
print('\x1B[34m msg \x1B[0m');
```

output:

[image]

`print` is coloured but the log is still white.
it's working on vscode but not working on android studio.

Comment: Have you any answer?